# Output a result of an SQL query to a PHP array

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to OOP in PHP, is that to seems correct ?

```
class whatever {

    Function Maths() {
    $this->sql->query($requete);

   $i = 0;

  while($val = mysql_fetch_array($this)) { 
    $tab[i][average] = $val['average'];
    $tab[i][randomData] = $val['sum'];
    $i=$i+1;
    }
        return $tab;
}
```

I want to access the data contained in the array

```
$foo = new whatever();
$foo->Maths();
 for ($i, $i <= endOfTheArray; i++) {

    echo Maths->tab[i][average];
    echo Maths->tab[i][randomData];
 }
```

Thank you ;)

EDIT: i want to output the result of  the SQL query as an array, so i can access it from outside the class

Comment: my question is : because i'm new to php OOP, i want to know if that i wrote here is right. It's supposed to output a result of an SQL query to an array to access it outside the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interest of helping you out, here are some modifications.  Please hear this, though: a lot of this might not make sense without a good background in PHP or OOP in general.  You should look at @webbiedave's link.

```
class whatever {

  static function maths() {
    $tabs = array();
    $results = $this->sql->query($requete);

    while($val = mysql_fetch_array($this)) { 
      $tabs = $val;
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

1. This fixes syntax errors and logic errors (for instance, the creation of the `$results` variable to hold the SQL query run).
2. I made the maths method static, since there's really no need to instantiate a `whatever()` object with this current example.

Here are some modifications to how this would be used:

```
$results = whatever::maths();
foreacho ($results as $result) {
  echo $result['average'];
  echo $result['randomData'];
}
```

1. Since maths() returns something, you need to store that in a variable; simply calling it, as you did previously, doesn't do anything.
2. That convoluted `for` loop can be replaced with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you, obviously i did a lot of confusing things before. I understand very well all your corrected code.
does a static call for Maths() function triggers the __construct of the Whatever class which recieve the database link connection in static ? 
Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: @webbiedave, I shall discover a way to send you points and do that pronto. ;)

Comment: @Tristan - not sure I understand your question, but calling a static method inside a class does *not* call a __construct() function.  If you want to do stuff in a constructor (like establish a database link), get rid of the `static` keyword in front of the method and instantiate the class in the manner you did previously.

Comment: perfect, you totally get the question since your answer answers it :D 
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Please check out PHP OOP basics:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

**Edit:** Thanks for cleaning up the code. Try something along the lines of:

```
$tabs = array();
while($val = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $tabs[] = $val;
}
```

And:

```
$foo = new whatever();
$tabs = $foo->Maths();
for ($tabs as $tab) {
    echo $tab['average'];
    echo $tab['randomData'];
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: ok, i've cleaned up a lot of things. Is that better this way ?

Comment: No - there are still several problems.  For instance, $foo->Maths(); won't do anything and trying to echo Maths->tab... will throw errors.  I agree that it is difficult to discern what you're trying to accomplish - can you tell us exactly what you want to do?

Comment: This "answer" should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I want to output the  result of the SQL query as an array, so i can access it from outside the class like <p> <?php print average ?></p>

Comment: The PHP manual isn't that great in explaining OOP to beginners. Google "PHP classes and OOP". there are some much better sites explaining OOP to newcomers.

Comment: thank you ;) i agree that PHP munual isn't kind of friendly to learn from for OOP ;)